Stop fabletools' autoplot from using color aesthetic for models when faceting
Q: When faceting by model, how can I stop fabletools::autoplot() from using the color aesthetic for models?
This is related to the question Facet a fabletools autoplot of a fable forecast by model. There was a great hack proposed in the comments. I replicate it below. But I don't imagine this is what the authors of fable intended. What's the non-hack approach?
I'm kind of struggling to understand how fabletools::autoplot() thinks about plotting, even after going through documentation and a debugging session. I think an answer to my specific question above will end up resolving some of my general struggles in understanding.
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)

tourism_melb <- tourism %>%
  filter(Region == "Melbourne") %>% 
  filter(Purpose == "Business") %>% 
  select(-Region, -State, -Purpose)

fableModels <- tourism_melb %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(), tslm = TSLM(Trips ~ trend()), mean = MEAN(window = 4))

forecasts <- fableModels %>% 
  forecast(h = "2 years")

forecasts %>% autoplot(tourism_melb) + facet_wrap(~.model, ncol = 1) +
# the great hack
scale_fill_manual(values = rep(NA, 3), aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), guide = "none")


These kind of autoplot methods generally don't implement a wide arrange of options. The idea is generally that they provide some useful/obvious plot. For anything more complicated, you will have to do things yourself. You can do this either by making model predictions and writing your own ggplot, or by taking the ggplot object and adding layers, facets, scales etc.

As @Axeman noted, many autoplot type functions are designed for convenience over customization. It's often simpler to build from scratch without using those functions if you want to alter how it works.
Here's one rough implementation for your case using normal ggplot2 functions, after extracting the quantile intervals using ggdist::median_qi (as the build_fbl_layer helper function of fabletools does). See https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/blob/master/R/plot.R
This should be more easily customizable.
ggplot(tourism_melb) +
  geom_line(aes(Quarter, Trips)) +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(Quarter, ymin = .lower, ymax = .upper, fill = "95%"),
    data = ggdist::median_qi(forecasts, Trips, .width = 0.95)) +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(Quarter, ymin = .lower, ymax = .upper, fill = "80%"),
    data = ggdist::median_qi(forecasts, Trips, .width = 0.8)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(Quarter, y = .mean), alpha = 0.3,
    data = forecasts) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#66666666", "#66666633")) +
  facet_wrap(~.model, ncol = 1) +
  labs(fill = "Level")


For comparison, here's the output I get from autoplot():

